# I need to add some conditions in "where", depending of a variable field value

Tags: mysql

I need to add conditions in my select depends of a variable field value. For example, if the field "x" is 10, in where I put "y" = 20, but if "x" is 11 I put "z" = 25 in where conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with this query:

```
SELECT whatever FROM your_table
WHERE (x = 10 AND y = 20)
   OR (x = 11 AND z = 25)
```

Parantheses are important here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
... WHERE (x = 10 AND y = 20) OR (x = 11 AND z = 25);
```

P. S. Also, your question could be better with sample data.